# A stacked bar plot (with percentage) of only one variable in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to make a stacked barplot of just one variable (option) for everyone in my data where the y-axis is percentages (so it ranges from 0 to 100%).

```
   id option
 1   1  1
 2   2  1
 3   2  2
 4   3  3
 5   4  4
 6   5  5
 7   6  1
 8   6  5
 9   6  6
 10  7  2
 11  7  3
 12  8  3
 13  8  5
 14  8  6
 15  9  2
 16 10  1
```

I have tried the codes below but could not get what I want

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x = '' ,y = option, fill = option)) +
 geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = 'identity') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

I want something like this, but just one bar with 6 different colors on it (because the option variable has 6 options) . Any help would be appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: @PabloRod no I want a 'stacked' bar plot. The ones they have above are separate bars...which I am trying to fix..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to change the options to a factor `df$option <- as.factor(df$option)`

Then `ggplot(df, aes(x='', fill=option)) + geom_bar(position = "fill")` And this will be the result.

[image: Stacked proportional plot]